# php array explode

Tags: php

I seem to be having a problem with the php array explode, I just cant seem to figure out why I am getting a count of 1 when this is ran, there is two entries in $imgURL and from my reading I should have an array with 2 slots. what am I doing wrong?

```
$imgURL = "../users/awmayhall/images/andrew1.jpg:../users/awmayhall/images/andrew2.jpg:";
$delimiter=":";
$itemList = array();
$itemList = explode($delimiter, $imgURL);
echo count(itemList);                               

for($i=0;$i<count(itemList);$i++)
{
    echo"<img src='".$imageLocation."' longdesc='".$imageLocation."'/>";
}
```

Comment: btw. you don't need `$itemList = array();`. `explode` already returns an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$ is missing

```
echo count($itemList);                              
       for($i=0;$i<count($itemList);$i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `count($itemList);`, you forgot the `$` before the variable. Apart from that, your code is fine but the array will contain 3 elements (an empty one). So you should remove the last `:` from your string or check every element, whether it is empty or not.

Furthermore you don't do anything with `$i` in your loop. Either you do:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($itemList);$i++) {
    if(!empty($itemList[$i])) {
        echo"<img src='".$itemList[$i] ."' longdesc='".$itemList[$i]."'/>";
    }
}
```

or use `foreach`:

```
foreach($itemList as $imageLocation) {
    if(!empty($imageLocation) {
        echo "<img src='".$imageLocation."' longdesc='".$imageLocation."'/>";
    }
}
```

And there is no need to initialize `$itemList` with an empty array.

If you want to have a cleaner separation of HTML and PHP (which you *should* want ;)), have a look at the [*alternative syntax for control structures*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

**How to detect such minor mistakes:**

You should set PHP's error reporting to `E_ALL`, while you are developing. Then you would get a notice:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo count(itemList);
```

> Notice: Use of undefined constant itemList - assumed 'itemList' in /private/tmp/dashphp.txt on line 4
>   1

As you can see, PHP interprets the non-existing constant as a string. [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) will return `1` for strings:

> If var is not an array or an object with implemented `Countable` interface, 1 will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

The array is `$itemList`, but after creating it you reference a nonexistant constant `itemList`. You lost your `$`.

```
$imgURL = "../users/awmayhall/images/andrew1.jpg:../users/awmayhall/images/andrew2.jpg:";
$itemList = explode(":", $imgURL);
foreach ($itemList as $item) {
    echo '<img src="' . $item . '" longdesc="' . $item . '" />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed a `$` on your itemlist.

try this:

```
<?php
$imgURL = "../users/awmayhall/images/andrew1.jpg:../users/awmayhall/images/andrew2.jpg:";
$delimiter=":";
$itemList = array();
$itemList = explode($delimiter, $imgURL);
foreach($itemList as $item)
{
  echo"<img src='".$item."' longdesc='".$item."'/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Becasue you are missing the `$` sign before it.

```
 echo count(itemList);
```

should be

```
 echo count($itemList);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have missed `$` in  `echo count(itemList);`

Answer (score 1):

Variables in PHP start with a dollar sign. If you leave it out, it's still valid PHP, but the variable name is interpreted as a constant; if the constant isn't defined, PHP interprets it as a string literal, even though you're not quoting it.